# SQL QUERY FROM MULTIPLE TABLES USING INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named INVOICE from Where i get ADDRESSID

I have another table named Address as

```
ADDRESSID         ADDRESS
2                 BB
2                 BC
```

And value of CC and BC are in another table named ADDRESSVALUE based on ADDRESSID

```
ID      CODE    VALUE
1        BB      BlindFold
2        BC      Bucharest
```

Now i query tables using inner join as

```
SELECT AC.VALUE AS ADDRESS 
FROM ADDRESS AS OT
INNER JOIN INVOICE AS OM ON  OM.ADDRESSID = OT.ADDRESSID
INNER JOIN ADDRESSVALUE AS AC ON OT.ADDRESS = AC.CODE
WHERE OM.ADDRESSID = 2
```

I am getting result as

```
Blindfold
Blindfold
```

But it should be

```
BlindFold
Bucharest
```

Comment: I don't think there should be any result at all. When you join ADDRESS with ADDRESSVALUE, there are no matches -- BB doesn't match Blindfold.

Comment: Sorry, its edited now.

Answer (score 1):

(Updated) One way to get the result you are looking for:

```
SELECT AC.VALUE AS ADDRESS 
FROM ADDRESS AS OT
INNER JOIN INVOICE AS OM ON  OM.ADDRESSID = OT.ADDRESSID
INNER JOIN ADDRESSVALUE AS AC ON OT.ADDRESS = AC.CODE
WHERE OM.ADDRESSID = @AddressID
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/98026/1).

Comment: Edited the question, please help now.

Answer (score 0):

Direclty use without join!

```
SELECT OM.VALUE AS ADDRESS 
FROM INVOICE AS OM WHERE OM.ADDRESSID = @AddressID
```

--

```
SELECT value FROM second_table WHERE code IN
(SELECT address FROM first_table WHERE addressid = @AddressID);
```

Comment: You're using two different aliases, but just one table. There's no VALUE column in the INVOICE table. And you're missing the WHERE keyword.

Comment: It gives me BlindFold two times

Comment: Are you sure?! Check with it again, and check the related queries in your part too.

Answer (score 0):

If the Address and the Addressvalue table should be joint through the column ADDRESSID which exists in both tables, then your select statement should include something like

```
ADDRESS.ADDRESSID = ADDRESSVALUE.ADDRESSID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT C.VALUE AS ADDRESS
FROM ADDRESS A
INNER JOIN INVOICE B ON A.ADDRESSID=B.ADDRESSID
INNER JOIN ADDRESSVALUE C ON A.ADDRESSID=C.ADDRESSID 
    AND A.ADDRESS=C.CODE
WHERE B.ADDRESSID=2
```

For Example, you can see  [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8cbc5/3)